# angular2: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: typescript, angular

I followed the angular2 [quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to create my project and everything works fine but my "tsc -w" command line keeps on telling me:

```
app/components/company/company.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
app/components/company/company.ts(5,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/components/mission/mission.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
app/components/mission/mission.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
```

And there is plenty of other line like this. However, everything is compiled successfully and my application works fine, but it's quite annoying to have all these warnings/errors as real errors something get lost in the middle of them.

I'm using Angular2 rc1, TypeScript 1.8.10, WebStorm EAP (altough I'm not using the WebStorm TypeScript compilation system, I'm relying on an open terminal with "tsc -w" command line).

I checked other question related to that on SO, but I didn't find anything that really helped me.

**Update**

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "js",
    "rootDir": "app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well... Apparently, this file already changed in the quick start since I created my project. In my typings, I just have "es6-shim", "jasmine" and "node". However, I see that now, in the quick start, "es6-shim" is replaced by "core-js", but I have the feeling that it won't solve my issue (am I wrong ?). Moreover, the solution proposed by "Thierry Templier" works. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use the `moduleResolution` attribute to `node`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node", // <-----
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "js",
    "rootDir": "app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It seems way better indeed. Could you just explain me in two words what it changes ?

Comment: It's the way the compiler will find out the `d.ts` files for contracts of libraries. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413533/what-is-the-purpose-of-tsconfig-json/37413595#37413595.

Comment: Somehow my editor still has `Cannot find module '@angular/core'`, even though this is in the `src/` tsconfig?

Answer (score 5):

You first need to add typings at global level as below.

```
npm install -g typings
```

Then create typings.json using below command.

```
typings init
```

Paste below code in typings.json

```
{
  "name": "ng2-application",
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

Now you need to add below code in tsconfig.json

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
       }
```

After doing above steps you will able to get definitions on F12.