# Adding tsconfig.json breaks module resolution

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have an Angular 2.4 + ASP.NET MVC Core project (targeting .NET 4.5). The project builds and works fine without any tsconfig.json file. When I add it the build fails with such errors in .ts files:

```
TS2307  Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

The tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I also tried `"module": "system"` or `"module": "commonjs"` also `"moduleResolution": "node"` settings but none of those didn't do any good. Project is using SystemJS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484442/angular2-cannot-find-module-angular-core add `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: @suraj: I've already tried moduleResolution setting. Didn't work for me.

Comment: you also havent added `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],` not sure if that is the problem. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#tsconfig